# Mac default Python

Tags: python, macos

How can i set the python on my mac back to the default reference location? When I to do

```
sudo easy_install virtualenv
```

I get the following results

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/a1ctesta/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
```

I do not have Canopy installed any longer so I wanted to restore this back to the original reference that came on the computer.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to modify your `$PATH` environment variable so that `/usr/bin` is before your custom path. To check if this is the issue, run the following command and see if `/usr/bin` is before or after your custom path

```
$ echo $PATH
```

The PATH environment variable is often set in `~/.bash_profile`, for example on my system I have

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Meaning that the `python` executable in `/opt/local/bin` takes precedence over the one in the default `PATH`.

Comment: I'm sure this worked for others, but it didn't work for me; however this did export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 2):

Make sure

> /usr/bin

precedes

> /Users/a1ctesta/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python

To do that:

1. In the terminal,

   > export PATH
   >   =/usr/bin:/Users/a1ctesta/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
2. Verify this using,

   > echo $PATH

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was easiest to reinstall Canopy. From the Canopy preferences menu, Unset Canopy as your default Python. Then restart your computer. https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469700-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. If you edit your ~/.bash_profile it will permanently fix the issue.

In terminal enter

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

It will then show something along the lines of

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH


# Added by Canopy installer on 2017-03-28
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make the bash prompt show that Canopy is active, otherwise 1
alias activate_canopy="source '/Users/chrisdunstan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'"
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source '/Users/chrisdunstan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'
```

Delete everything added by the Canopy installer and press ^O to save and then ^X to close. Restart terminal and it should use the built-in python compiler.

Another solution I found was to re-install Canopy and then go to Preferences and unselect Canopy as the default python compiler.